# Drag a item from Treeview to ListBox on Windows Forms (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, listbox, treeview

I'm Writing an application in Windows forms with a File Explorer TreeView and I need a way to get the Node.FullPath in string to a ListBox using Drag and Drop.

yesterday I found this question about it:

[C# Drag & drop from listbox to treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495666/c-sharp-drag-drop-from-listbox-to-treeview)

but I need the exactly oposite and maybe a way to hold Shitf and do the selection with more than one Node to proceed drag and drop with them

Comment: Drag and drop is the same concept which ever way you go, try working on that info and ask for specific help with issues.

Comment: Treeview doesn't support multiselect, so either simply go for checkboxes or learn how to buld a [multiselect-treeview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206096/how-do-i-allow-multi-select-in-a-net-treeview).  Not exactly simple though.. After studying a few drag&drop examples you should be able to tackle it. Come back when you have not just an aim but code and a problem with it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag&Drop is the same concept, there is the code that I used to make it happen.

```
    private void tvDiretorios2_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        //pega os Selecionados e colocar em uma lista
        List<string> listaSelecionados = new List<string>();
        foreach (TreeNode tN in tvDiretorios.SelectedNodes)
        {
            listaSelecionados.Add(tN.FullPath.ToString());
        }
        DoDragDrop(listaSelecionados, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    private void tvDiretorios2_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //Depois de DoDragDrop Existi- 2°Passo. Confirma que o que foi puxado é uma lista
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(List<string>)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }




    /** EVENTOS DROP DA LISTA */
    private void lbConvertidas_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //Determina se o o objeto pode ser arrastado para o lbConvertidas
        if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(List<string>)))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private void lbConvertidas_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //Toma alguma ação quando ele for solto
        //Importar(); -- Ação Principal
        var lista = e.Data.GetData(typeof(List<string>)) as List<string>;
        if (lista != null)
            lbConvertidas.Items.AddRange(lista.ToArray()); //será convertido 
    }
```

But to select more then One Node I used an alternative TreeView component, source link is down below.

http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/treeviewms.html

I Created a simple checking routine just to know that I'm in the right direction.

```
 private void BuscarSelecionados()
    {
        foreach (TreeNode tN in tvDiretorios2.SelectedNodes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(tN.FullPath.ToString(), "Atenção");
        }
    }
```

The key is using this alternative TreeNode Component.

Thanks anyway to the ones who tried to help...and the ones you didn't...