# Cannot Populate TreeView Control with Win32 Messages in CSharp

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with `TreeView Control` in `Windows Forms` in `C#`.

Since actual population part of `TreeView Control` takes a lot of time it freezes the UI. So I'm attempting to do the population using `PostMessage Win32 API` from a background thread but I found that the `Treeview` isn't getting inserted with Items.

So I moved the code from background thread to main thread. But then also the Insert Item Code is not working. I got similar code working with `TreeView` in `C++` and trying to do the same thing with `C#` using interop routines.

I'm not going the usual `C#` way of `treeView1.Nodes.Add("...")` because it freezes the UI even if I follow the `Delegate` method and `BackgroundWorker` method for populating UI controls from another thread. I'm giving the code I use below. Can some one please help to find the issue with the code.

Also Please note for the `TreeView` Control I'm using my own simple class derived from `TreeView` class, where I have overriden the `WndProc` method to verify the flow of Windows Messages and I can see the messages(`TVM_INSERTITEM`) are actually getting through but still the item is not getting populated

Also I have got similar interop code working fine from Background Thread for `ListView` Control but my attempts with `TreeView` haven't succeeded so far.

**Form Class Code**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace UpdateTreeViewFromAnotherThread
{
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct TVITEM
{
    public uint mask;
    public IntPtr hItem;
    public uint state;
    public uint stateMask;
    public IntPtr pszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public int iSelectedImage;
    public int cChildren;
    public uint lParam;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct TVINSERTSTRUCT
{
    public IntPtr hParent;
    public IntPtr hInsertAfter;
    public TVITEM item;
}

public enum TreeViewInsert
{
    TVI_ROOT = -0x10000,
}

[Flags]
public enum TreeViewItemMask
{
    TVIF_TEXT = 0x0001,
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int TV_FIRST = 0x1100;
    IntPtr tvInsItemPtr;
    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins;
    IntPtr handleTreeView;

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    public enum TreeViewMessage
    {
        TVM_INSERTITEM = TV_FIRST + 50,        
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        handleTreeView = treeView1.Handle;
        //treeView1.Nodes.Add("hello");
        PopulateTree(handleTreeView);
    }

    public void PopulateTree(IntPtr handle)
    {
        tvins = new TVINSERTSTRUCT();
        tvins.item.mask = (uint)TreeViewItemMask.TVIF_TEXT;

        // Set the text of the item. 
        string productName = "Product";
        string value = productName;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value + "\0");
        tvins.item.pszText = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, tvins.item.pszText, buffer.Length);

        tvins.hParent = IntPtr.Zero;
        tvins.hInsertAfter = (IntPtr)(TreeViewInsert.TVI_ROOT);
        tvInsItemPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tvins));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(tvins, tvInsItemPtr, true);
        PostMessage(treeView1.Handle, (uint)TreeViewMessage.TVM_INSERTITEM, IntPtr.Zero, tvInsItemPtr);
        //SendMessage(treeView1.Handle, (int)TreeViewMessage.TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, tvInsItemPtr);
    }
}
}
```

**MyTreeView Class Code**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace UpdateTreeViewFromAnotherThread
{
    class MyTreeView:TreeView
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x1132)
            {
                TVINSERTSTRUCT anotherTVInsertStruct;
                anotherTVInsertStruct = (TVINSERTSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(TVINSERTSTRUCT));
                string anotherNodeText = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(anotherTVInsertStruct.item.pszText);
            }
            if(m.Msg == 0x113F)
            {
                TVITEM anotherTVItem;
                anotherTVItem = (TVITEM)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(TVITEM));
                string anotherNodeText = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(anotherTVItem.pszText);
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            //Trace.WriteLine(m.Msg.ToString() + ", " + m.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Update_1**

Prevented NM_CUSTOMDRAW for Treeview using the below code. Thanks to the code at[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864875/10828120).

```
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_REFLECT + WM_NOTIFY:
                {
                    NMHDR nmhdr = (NMHDR)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDR));
                    switch ((int)nmhdr.code)
                    {
                        case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
                            NMTVCUSTOMDRAW nmTvDraw = (NMTVCUSTOMDRAW)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMTVCUSTOMDRAW));
                            switch (nmTvDraw.nmcd.dwDrawStage)
                            {
                                case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
                                    m.Result = (IntPtr)CDRF_DODEFAULT;
                                    break;
                            }
                            Marshal.StructureToPtr(nmTvDraw, m.LParam, false);
                            return;
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

So Now If I change my earlier PopulateTree function (note Thread.Sleep()) and its invocation to a background thread as below it will not freeze the UI during the population process

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        handleTreeView = treeView1.Handle;
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(() => PopulateTree(handleTreeView));
        backgroundThread.Start();
    }

    public void PopulateTree(IntPtr handle)
    {
        for(int i =0; i< 1000; i++)
        { 
            tvins = new TVINSERTSTRUCT();
            tvins.item.mask = (uint)TreeViewItemMask.TVIF_TEXT;

            // Set the text of the item. 
            string productName = "Product_" + i.ToString();
            string value = productName;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
            buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value + "\0");
            tvins.item.pszText = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, tvins.item.pszText, buffer.Length);

            tvins.hParent = IntPtr.Zero;
            tvins.hInsertAfter = (IntPtr)(TreeViewInsert.TVI_ROOT);
            tvInsItemPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tvins));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(tvins, tvInsItemPtr, true);
            PostMessage(handle, (uint)TreeViewMessage.TVM_INSERTITEM, IntPtr.Zero, tvInsItemPtr);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the).  **Short answer:** even if you could, updating the UI from a worker thread isn't going to make it faster.  You might want to look into [`TreeView.BeginUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beginupdate?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Hi MickyD thanks for the quick response. But my problem is UI responsiveness. Showing wait cursor is not an option. I have managed to get List view control populated by similar code from background thread. So if  I put a sleep in the for loop of the thread populating the TreeView control, I can see ListView getting filled up one item by one. I can drag around my window while it is getting populated. So though it says cross thread operation is not valid i have it working for ListView.. and UI doesn't freeze.. So in short it doesn't resolve my issue..

Comment: You can use `Control.BeginInvoke()`. This method uses `RegisterWindowMessage` and `PostMessage` to marshal the call to the Thread where the Control was created. You can run a Task (`Task.Run(() => [Method()])`) and, in a BeginUpdate/EndUpdate section you `BeginInvoke()` the Control. You don't need 90% of all that. There are some notes about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571698/7444103) (another language, but all .NET stuff).

Comment: _"...But my problem is UI responsiveness"_ - Agreed.  That's why you should look into _freezing updates_ via calls to methods such as `BeginUpdate`.  Also, you should look into _batched_ updates. i.e. not inserting everything at once.  Whilst it is fine to use a worker thread to calculate _what_ items need to be added, you should marshal the batch over to the UI thread to actually _add_ them.  This is a common practice.  It removes the wait cursor without thrashing your UI pump

Comment: Jimi, Micky D thanks for your updates... I believe both of you guys are referring to the same approach. I will try it out

Comment: I got a solution at this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75f23fba-8937-43bf-a351-fb32ae5b46a8/cannot-populate-treeview-control-with-windows-messages-in-csharp?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues&prof=required). I prevented NM_CUSTOMDRAW as suggested using the code that I have updated in my question. But I will be pursuing the BeginUpdate and BeginInvoke methods as mentioned by Jimi and Micky D as it seems to be the more C# way of doing things.. Need to see whether the UI responsiveness is same as that of the approach Preventing NM_CUSTOMDRAW approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jimi and MikiD I was able to produce same non-freezing UI behaviour using the BeginUpdate and BeginInvoke approach. I changed my code as below

```
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => PopulateTree());
    }

    private async void PopulateTree()
    {
        for(int i = 0;i< 1000;i++)
        {
            treeView1.BeginInvoke( (MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    treeView1.BeginUpdate();
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add("Product_" + i.ToString());
                    treeView1.EndUpdate();
                }
            );

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```